# Strange IE11 HTML5 Video Issue

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video, windows-7, internet-explorer-11

I have been stumped before, but never quite like this. Please bear with me.

I have embedded an MP4 video into a web page using the HTML5 video tag as follows:

```
<video poster="/media/video/cick_away_poster.png" controls width="560" height="315">
<source src="http://www.lpcsc.k12.in.us/media/video/click_away.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<p>Your browser does not support this video.</p>
</video>
```

The page is hosted in house, on our corporation website. I tried both relative and absolute links, then used the complete URL to the video for troubleshooting on different servers outside of our network. More on this later.

I didn't think there was an issue until a few people in our corporation informed me that they could not see the video in IE11 on their PC.

- I had them try it in Chrome and it worked fine.
- I double-checked it in both IE11 and Chrome on my PC and it works
  fine
- I tried it on a freshly cast, fully updated Windows 7 PC, and it did
  not work and just shows "Your browser does not support this video."
- I tried it in Chrome on the new PC, and it works fine.
- I used just the bare code needed for the video. No change.

At this point, I am already scratching my head. Why would it work on some machines and not others, but ONLY in IE11? Some coworkers can see it, yet others cannot?

Moving on:

- I created a page on our Intranet server (also IIS) and another server
  (Apache) and tested it. Same results.
- I created a page on a test server at my home and tested it from the
  new PC located in my office. Voila! It worked! Wait...what?
- I located other HTML5 videos on other external sites, and all of them
  also played on the same machine using IE11.
- I tried the original page once again, just for kicks, and nothing.
- I changed my IP to the IP of the new machine and vice versa. Nothing
- I compared IE settings, security settings, made sure Windows Firewall
  was disabled on both machines, compared network settings...you name
  it. Nothing.

Now I am ready to drink. It makes no sense...

Just because, I decided instead of accessing the site using the FQDN, I'd try via the server's IP address. Bingo....it works. Huh?

To review:

- In Chrome using FQDN - Video appears on all machines
- In IE11 using FQDN - Hit and miss...appears on some, not on others.
- In IE11 using pages hosted externally - Video appears on all machines
- In IE11 using IP address of internally hosted server - Video appears on all machines

It led me to consider a DNS issue, but why would it work in Chrome on all machines? It is specific to IE, but only on SOME machines. I even flushed DNS for kicks....nothing.

I pointed this out to our network admin, and he is equally as stumped. No errors, it just acts like the browser is not HTML5 compliant when using the FQDN on some machines.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Seems I have answered my own question:

We are a large corporation and we image all of our Windows machines. The coworker who creates most of our images added our domain to the **Compatibility Mode** list in IE. Makes total sense now that I think about the behavior that was occurring, I just never thought about the fact that some machines were imaged while others were not.